# Example code not working on php developers site

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

The third example code on https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/code_samples/php#uploading_a_new_reference__so_youtube_can_automatically_generate_claims_for_newly_uploaded_videos_on_behalf_of_the_asset_s_owner isn’t working.

Even if you use the `YouTubePartner.php` file you can found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/clientlib/Google-youtubePartner-v1-20140110-php-1.0.0-alpha.zip (but still isn’t on github `/Google/Service/` ), this is the error you get:

`An client error occurred: Error calling PUT googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets/A767977048508576/…: (400) You cannot identify a <code><a href="/youtube/partner/docs/v1/publishers">publisher</a></code> as the owner of a non-composition asset.`

Something inside that `YouTubePartner.php` file seems to be not working.

Could you please fix it?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I got this error earlier , because of a problem in the library. It was setting publisher in the JSON call. So it has nothing to do with YouTube API nor your code. I'll try it today and talk with library guys to make sure it's fixed, or at least give you built of the library that's working fine.

Comment: This was the version working for me, right after this commit. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/commit/a23485a2b42cef7f9e4ebd62a1ee6466ef070515   If you can check out that version, you should be ok.

Comment: We're trying the version with with the commit you've point us at with no success.

We get the same error: (in next comment)

Last 1.0.1-beta version doesn't work, by the way.
In both of them, we add the YouTubePartner.php file you gave us before.
How could you make it? Should we try another way or code? Could we help you anyhow?
Thanks again for your time.

Comment: The same error:

An client error occurred: Error calling PUT https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/partner/v1/assets/A311514762529371/ownership?onBehalfOfContentOwner=Altafonte: (400) You cannot identify a <code><a href="/youtube/partner/docs/v1/publishers">publisher</a></code> as the owner of a non-composition asset.

Comment: If you need the fix immediately, you can use his branch.
https://github.com/ianbarber/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

There's no "fix", your answer is in the error:

```
> You cannot identify a <code><a
> href="/youtube/partner/docs/v1/publishers">publisher</a></code> as the
> owner of a non-composition asset.
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope. I think you’re wrong:

1) We’re running the code without any modification (except for includes routes, authentication variables, and $referenceVideoPath, obviously): IT’S NOT WORKING.

2) Three weeks ago we were able to made it with the 0.6.7 API in a flash!, but the example has changed since then (to migrate to v1.0.0), and the YouTubePartner.php file also changed.

3) We know that our authentication is ok, because the first example on that page works perfectly: the authentication works good there.

4) The steps 1 and 2 on third example are working, but then fails at 3rd.

If you’re able of make it run ok, please tell us how you’ve made it. It will be very appreciated… We’re lost and stuck.

Did you test it and made it running ok?

Thank you very much.